# PHP: Group array corresponding to it's date

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have an array that list datetime. How to group the array that has the same date.

```
$array = [
   "2019-07-17 10:02:00",
   "2019-07-17 12:00:00",
   "2019-07-18 08:00:00",
   "2019-07-19 01:00:00",
   "2019-07-19 02:00:00"
];
```

Expected **result** :

```
$result = [
       0 => [
            "2019-07-17 10:02:00",
            "2019-07-17 12:00:00"
       ],
      1 => [
            "2019-07-18 08:00:00"
       ],
       2 => [
            "2019-07-19 01:00:00",
            "2019-07-19 02:00:00"
       ]
];
```

Comment: So, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$grouped = [];
foreach ($array as $dateString) {
    $dateObject = new \DateTime($dateString);
    $grouped[$dateObject->format('Y-m-d')][] = $dateString;
}
$grouped = array_values($grouped);
var_dump($grouped);
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9a6644453a2eafebb52ac751d97c78fcef67d0b5).

Comment: Without `array_values` it will return array with dates in keys. Like `['2019-07-17' => ["2019-07-17 10:02:00"], '2019-07-18' => ["2019-07-18 10:02:00"]]`. array_values will give `[0 => ["2019-07-17 10:02:00"], 1 => ["2019-07-18 10:02:00"]]`.